# Create MP4 container for .ts segment

Tags: android, video, http-live-streaming

I want to play static HLS content (not live video content) on my app in Android. What I currently do is download all the segments from the .m3u8 file and merge it into one file. When I play this file, I can see this the video being played, but it is not seekable. As per this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), .ts files are not seekable on Android.

I cannot risk running ffmpeg on phone for converting the file to MP4 format. I have studied MP4 format and its atom structure. **What I want to know is, if there is an easy way to create MP4 container (atoms hierarchy) which would simply refer to the .ts segment (the merged segment that was created from sub-segments) in its data atom (mdat)**

I would really appreciate any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android provides support libraries such as MediaCodec and MediaExtractor that provides access to low level media encoding/decoding. It is fast and efficient as it uses hardware acceleration.

Here's how I believe one is suppose to do it on Android unless you are ok with using ffmpeg which of course if resource intensive operation.

1) Use MediaExtractor to extract data from the file.

2) Pass the extracted data to MediaCodec.

3) Use MediaCodec to render output to a surface (in case of video) and AudioTrack (in case of audio).

4) This is the most difficult step: Synchronize audio/video. I haven't implemented this yet. But this would require keeping track of time sync between audio and video. Audio would be played normally and you might have to drop some frames in case of video to keep it in sync with audio playback.

Here's code for decoding audio/video and playing them respectively using AudioTrack and Surface.
In case of video decoding, there's a sleep to slowdown the frame rendering.

```
public void decodeVideo(Surface surface) throws IOException {
    MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    MediaCodec codec;
    ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers;
    ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers;

    extractor.setDataSource(file);

    Log.d(TAG, "No of tracks = " + extractor.getTrackCount());
    MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(0);

    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
    Log.d(TAG, "mime = " + mime);
    Log.d(TAG, "format = " + format);

    codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
    codec.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    codec.start();
    codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
    codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

    extractor.selectTrack(0);

    final long timeout_in_Us = 5000;
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    boolean sawInputEOS = false;
    boolean sawOutputEOS = false;
    int noOutputCounter = 0;

    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(!sawOutputEOS && noOutputCounter < 50) {
        noOutputCounter++;
        if(!sawInputEOS) {
            int inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeout_in_Us);

            if(inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer dstBuf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0);

                long presentationTimeUs = 0;

                if(sampleSize < 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawInputEOS = true;
                    sampleSize = 0;
                } else {
                    presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                }

                codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, sampleSize, presentationTimeUs, sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);

                if(!sawInputEOS) {
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }

        }

        int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, timeout_in_Us);

        if(res >= 0) {

            if(info.size > 0) {
                noOutputCounter = 0;
            }

            int outputBufIndex = res;

            while(info.presentationTimeUs/1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, true);

            if((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw output EOS.");
                sawOutputEOS = true;
            }

        } else if(res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
            Log.d(TAG, "output buffers have changed.");

        } else if(res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format1 = codec.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d(TAG, "output format has changed to " + format1);
        } else if(res == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Codec try again returned" + res);
        }
    }

    codec.stop();
    codec.release();
}

private int audioSessionId = -1;
private AudioTrack createAudioTrack(MediaFormat format) {
    int channelConfiguration = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT) == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
    int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE), channelConfiguration, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 8;

    AudioTrack audioTrack;
    if(audioSessionId == -1) {
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE), channelConfiguration,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    } else {
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE), channelConfiguration,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM, audioSessionId);
    }
    audioTrack.play();
    audioSessionId = audioTrack.getAudioSessionId();
    return audioTrack;
}

public void decodeAudio() throws IOException {
    MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    MediaCodec codec;
    ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers;
    ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers;

    extractor.setDataSource(file);

    Log.d(TAG, "No of tracks = " + extractor.getTrackCount());
    MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(1);

    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
    Log.d(TAG, "mime = " + mime);
    Log.d(TAG, "format = " + format);

    codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
    codec.configure(format, null, null, 0);
    codec.start();
    codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
    codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

    extractor.selectTrack(1);

    AudioTrack audioTrack = createAudioTrack(format);

    final long timeout_in_Us = 5000;
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    boolean sawInputEOS = false;
    boolean sawOutputEOS = false;
    int noOutputCounter = 0;

    while(!sawOutputEOS && noOutputCounter < 50) {
        noOutputCounter++;
        if(!sawInputEOS) {
            int inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeout_in_Us);

            if(inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer dstBuf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0);

                long presentationTimeUs = 0;

                if(sampleSize < 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawInputEOS = true;
                    sampleSize = 0;
                } else {
                    presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                }

                codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, sampleSize, presentationTimeUs, sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);

                if(!sawInputEOS) {
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }

        }

        int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, timeout_in_Us);
        if(res >= 0) {

            if(info.size > 0) {
                noOutputCounter = 0;
            }

            int outputBufIndex = res;
            //Possibly store the decoded buffer
            ByteBuffer buf = codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];
            final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
            buf.get(chunk);
            buf.clear();

            if(chunk.length > 0) {
                audioTrack.write(chunk, 0 ,chunk.length);
            }

            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);

            if((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw output EOS.");
                sawOutputEOS = true;
            }

        } else if(res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
            Log.d(TAG, "output buffers have changed.");

        } else if(res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format1 = codec.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d(TAG, "output format has changed to " + format1);
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack = createAudioTrack(codec.getOutputFormat());
        } else if(res == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Codec try again returned" + res);
        }
    }

    codec.stop();
    codec.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without a copy. TS is uses 188 byte packets with headers. These headers create breaks in the middle of frames. In mp4, frames must be contiguous.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I guess it makes sense why I was not able to play it. Do you know if there is a way to decode TS file, get the frames and then use it to create a MP4. I know this is what ffmpeg does, but its source code is very complicated. Besides, I am thinking of having a JAVA based implementation. In your opinion, is there a better approach to handle this?

Comment: You don't want to decode. You only want to transmux. I don't know what libs are available in Java, but you can always write your own.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I plan to do. Do you know of any references that might be useful for trasmux. Or if you could suggest how to proceed. All these video formatting is new to me. I mean, I have been using these formats forever but only to play videos and never on such granular level.

Comment: The wikipedia article in transport stream i surpassingly good. you will also need to know about elementary streams formats. Mp3 frame headers, ADTS headers, sequence headers/extra data. etc. I have a post about AVCVC specifically here http://szatmary.org/blog/25

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This is what I'm planning to do. Please correct me if I am wrong.
First, I need to grab the elementary streams from the TS file (audio and video).
Second, figure out some how to put these streams inside a MP4 container.

Will this approach work?